# Bind or Lambda for member function callback c++14

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, bind

Just inquiring which is a better choice in newer versions of c++ to handle callbacks of member functions.
Any help would be much appreciated, hopefully the example will help also.

```
template<class T>
void addCallBack(void(T::*someFunc)(int), T* instance) {
    func = std::bind(someFunc, instance, _1);
}
std::function<void(int)> func ;
```

or

```
template<class T>
void addCallBack(T* instance) {
    func = [&instance](int x) {
        instance->someFunc(x);
    }
}
std::function<void(int)> func;
```

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: Lambdas are almost always better than `bind` in terms of performance (and in terms of clarity, in my opinion).

Comment: More appropriate for the job, correct way, good programming practice etc.
I understand there are 100's of ways of doing most things in c++ and would like to know is there a correct way in this case or does it matter ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
template<class T>
void addCallBack(T* instance) {
    func = [&instance](int x) {
        instance->someFunc(x);
    }
}
```

is capturing the argument `instance` by reference, which goes out of scope at the end of `addCallBack()` so you end up with a dangling reference. So, definitely **not** that.

What you want to do is:

```
func = [instance](int x){ instance->someFunc(x); }
```

or just:

```
func = [=](int x){ instance->someFunc(x); }
```

Now there isn't going to be a functional difference<sup>†</sup> between that and:

```
func = std::bind(&T::someFunc, instance, std::placeholders::_1);
```

but the lambda is going to be typically easier to read (as it is in this case), and easier to inline, and is more capable of doing arbitrary complex things. The latter two don't matter in this case - but are good reasons to basically always prefer lambdas.

---

<sup>†</sup>Of course, this doesn't work if `someFunc` is an overloaded name, which is one more reason to prefer a lambda - which will always work.

Comment: There is no practical functional difference, but you can actually extract the bind expression with care from the std function as the type (while insanely complex) is not guaranteed unique like the lambda is.   So not *no* functional difference.  Just no practical difference in a sane codebase.